# How to read value from custom user field in Workflow 2013

Tags: workflow, visual-studio

I have a custom user field (it's used in custom task content type):

```
<Field ID="{d3773326-a0a8-45e2-9c60-82fc7f7ba01c}" Name="IM_Task_ResponsiblePerson" DisplayName="Responsible person" Type="User" Group="Issue Manager"></Field>
```

I need to read a value (and its properties) from this column in Workflow 2013.
*How can I do this?*

VisualStudio says that this field have string value in GetDynamicValueProperties activity. But I need an int value for use it in LookupSPUser activity.
Or maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the field name with GetDynamicValueProperties and assign the value to a variable of type `int`.

[image]

You might need to postfix the field name with "Id" as explained here: http://mazdev.blogspot.ae/2014/05/get-value-of-persongroup-list-item.html

Take a look at this question: [Declarative SharePoint 2013 Workflow Sending Email to Person Specific in Item List Field of Type Person/Group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98196/declarative-sharepoint-2013-workflow-sending-email-to-person-specific-in-item-li)