# Declarative SharePoint 2013 Workflow Sending Email to Person Specific in Item List Field of Type Person/Group

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, email

I've been looking everywhere... for days. (I'm stubborn so I don't like asking questions before trying.) So here is the hardest question ever:

I have a SharePoint Online (2013) Custom List on which I'm running a Workflow. The association shows so the Workflow actually runs, and I receive email from it to one of the hard-wired emails.

The problem is getting an email dynamically, from a Person/Group field in the list. I have a field named ResponsiblePerson. When I try to get the value of that field (all I care about this "Person/Group" is the email), it seems to come as a null or empty string value.

I've tried many different variations to the following:

First I get the item.

[image: sharepoint workflow lookup]

Then I get values from the item. I just get ResponsiblePerson and put it in a variable called rp1. I tried to make this variable of type dynamic and string. Both didn't work, as I get an empty value in the email (see next step).

[image: dynamic prop values]

Finally, I send an email.

[image: email activity]

This email is addresses to a static email for testing. I get an empty rp1 otherwise I would have specified it in the To of the email activity (within a collection) and we would be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the field name + "Id".

Here is where I blog about this: http://mazdev.blogspot.ae/2014/05/get-value-of-persongroup-list-item.html