# Get User from List Item in Visual Studio 2012 workflow for Sharepoint 2013

Tags: workflow, visual-studio-2012

Got to implement a seq. workflow based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn584771(v=office.15).aspx#bm3

Notice: My Entity Type is "ListItem" (the workflow will be bound to the relevant list after deployment!)

A GetDynamicValueProperties activity shall get the Content of a field "customer" of type "Person".

**How to get what's in the field "customer" of the current list item**?

Studying other docs there's advised to use LookupSPUser activity. Is this the right way and if so how to get the necessary ID (= id of the value in "customer")?

similar post:
[How to read value from custom user field in Workflow 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/90551/how-to-read-value-from-custom-user-field-in-workflow-2013)

further study:
http://www.sharepoint-journey.com/get-user-information-in-visual-studio-workflow-in-sharepoint-hosted-app.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so I found:

http://mazdev.blogspot.ae/2014/05/get-value-of-persongroup-list-item.html

the solution is to write "Id" directly after the field name within the GetDynamicValueProperties Path.

intuitional? hmh, may be...

further links:

[Declarative SharePoint 2013 Workflow Sending Email to Person Specific in Item List Field of Type Person/Group](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/98196/declarative-sharepoint-2013-workflow-sending-email-to-person-specific-in-item-li)